# Где граница между прилагательным и причастием?

Tags: части-речи, прилагательные, причастия

Смотрю слово *асфальтированный*:

> (1)
>
> Страдательное причастие, совершенного вида, прошедшего времени, тип
>   склонения по классификации А. Зализняка — 1*a(2).
>
> *Викисловарь*
>
> (2)
>
> асфальтированный (прил.)
>
> Из прич. по знач. сов. глаг.: асфальтировать.
>
> *Словарь Ефремовой*

Используя словосочетание:

> асфальтированная дорога

акцент идёт на результат, свойство — дорога покрыта слоем асфальта  — а не на процесс, на временную характеристику.

**Вопрос:** где в русском языке проходит граница между причастием и прилагательным?

Answer (score 3):

Границы действительно размыты, но они есть. Главное различие уже назвали: **причастие** – форма глагола, обозначающая признак по действию (или процессуальный признак). У причастий есть грамматическое значение вида и времени.**Прилагательное** обозначает постоянный, вневременно'й признак предмета.

Причастия могут изменять свое значение, тогда они называют не признак предмета по действию (это грамматическое значение причастия), а постоянный признак. Так возникают прилагательные, омонимичные причастиям. Ср.: образовать – новый факультет, образованный в институте по приказу министерства (причастие, его образовали), образованный человек, то есть «просвещенный, культурный, начитанный» (прилагательное, здесь нет процесса, его никто не образовывал).

Краткое причастие или краткое прилагательное?

Краткие причастия могут иметь при себе зависимые слова – дополнения в форме творительного падежа или обстоятельства места и времени: Продукты заморожены (кем? где?), следы запутаны (кем? где?) – краткое причастие. Ответы путаны(= неясны) – краткое прилагательное. Обычно краткие прилагательные типа величественны, воспитанны выступают в предложениях в роли однородного члена с другим прилагательным: Девушка умна и образованна. Ср.: Сестра воспитана в семье отчима (причастие).

Отличить причастие от прилагательного можно довольно простым способом. Попробуйте вставить в предложении слово после предполагаемого причастия или прилагательного, подходящее ему по смыслу. Например, в предложении «Мы увидели летящих птиц» можно вставить подходящее по смыслу слово «по небу». «Мы увидели летящих по небу птиц». Слово «летящих» в данном случае является причастием.

В предложении «Она подошла к нам летящей походкой» мы не можем вставить подходящего слова к слову «летящая», т.к. это – прилагательное и находится в прямой зависимости от существительного «походка»

Есть ещё признаки, по которым можно определить часть речи (отглагольное прилагательное или причастие):

1) Отглагольные прилагательные образуются только от глаголов несовершенного вида: кипяченое молоко от кипятить, жженая пробка от жечь.

Но есть целый ряд отглагольных прилагательных-исключений: деланный, жеманный, виденный, желанный, чванный, чеканный, окаянный, медленный, священный, невиданный, неслыханный, нежданный, негаданный, нечаянный, считанный, недрёманное око.

Если же форма образована от глагола совершенного вида, то это причастие: решенная задача от решить, брошенные вещи от бросить. Исключения:смышленый, названый — с одним н.

2) У отглагольных прилагательных нет приставок: жареная котлета, путаный ответ. Если к прилагательному прибавляется приставка не-, то оно остается прилагательным и пишется с одним н: гашеная известь — негашеная известь; глаженое белье — неглаженое белье.

У причастий могут быть приставки: под-жаренное мясо, за-путанные следы.

3) У отглагольных прилагательных нет зависимых слов: сушеные грибы, квашеная капуста. У причастий могут быть зависимые слова: сушенные на солнцегрибы, квашенная на зиму капуста.

4) Отглагольные слова на -ованный, -еванный — прилагательные, они всегда пишутся с двумя н (прессованный, корчеванный).

Прилагательные кованый, жеваный,пишутся с одним н, так как -ов и -ев входят в корень, в чем убеждаемся, разобрав слова по составу.

Следовательно, если мы рассматриваем форму, образованную от глагола, которая не имеет приставки или зависимого слова, то прежде чем решить, причастие это или прилагательное, следует определить вид глагола, от которого эта форма образована.

Полезно сопоставить смешиваемые формы:

масляные (краски) — прилагательное, образованное от существительного масло с помощью суффикса -ян;

масленый (блин) — отглагольное прилагательное, образованное от глагола маслить; замасленный (фартук) — причастие, образованное от глагола замаслить.

В  кратких прилагательных сохраняется столько н, сколько было в полных, а краткие страдательные причастия всегда пишутся с одним н.

[Как отличить отглагольное прилагательное от причастия?](http://www.genon.ru/GetAnswer.aspx?qid=d1687a03-b71b-41c7-9bb8-f40a117abd46)

Comment: Слово СЧИТАН(Н)ЫЙ в ряду приведённых исключений вызывает сомнения.  Привожу цитату из Лопатина: "Прилагательное разыскной пишется по общему правилу написания приставки раз-/роз-, с буквой а (в безударном положении в этой приставке пишется только а), а прилагательные деланый («искусственный») и считаный («очень небольшой»: считаное количество) ― по общему правилу, с одним н (в отличие от соответствующих страдательных причастий). [В. Лопатин. О новом академическом справочнике по русскому языку // «Наука и жизнь», 2008]"

Comment: Это так, но смотря  кем задан вопрос. Если для подготовки к экзамену в школе, то учебники переиздаются по старым правилам, последних изменений там нет, задания ЕГЭ тоже без изменений. Если вуз, нужно приводить 2 версии - старую и новую

Comment: Хороший учитель не к ЕГЭ готовит, а учит грамотно писать и говорить. Он всегда подвергает анализу материалы любого учебника и очень тщательно отбирает информацию, пользуясь, кроме учебника, целым рядом других источников. Неважно, кем задан вопрос. Важна только истина."Считаный" в значении "малочисленный" пишется с одной Н. Почему в словари попал неверный вариант написания - вот вопрос. В последнее время такие случаи, к сожалению,  нередки.

Comment: Поэтому я и говорю, что не к чему правила менять, и старые-то ещё не выучили, а тут ещё переучиваться. Кто как заучил, так и будет писать. И словари менять никто не захочет,стоят они всё-таки дорого. Вот в Ожегове считанный -НН- зачем кому-то проверять его правильность?Лопатин всё перелопатил, а все расхлёбывай. А вот кто и зачем задаёт вопрос, для меня важно, ведь от моего ответа зависит, помогу я ему или наврежу. Если ученик на ЕГЭ получит 2 из-за моих умствований, я рада не буду

Answer (score 1):

> **Прича́стие** — это особая неспрягаемая форма глагола, которая, обозначая действие, представляет его *как признак предмета* (признак по действию, процессуальный признак): бегущий спортсмен — спортсмен *(какой?)*, который *(что делает?)* бежит; уехавший друг — друг *(какой?)*, который *(что сделал?)* уехал; изучаемая учениками тема — тема *(какая?)*, которую ученики *(что делают?)* изучают; открытое окно — окно *(какое?)*, которое *(что сделали с окном?)* открыли. Ср. признак предмета, обозначаемый прилагательным (желтые листья — листья желтого цвета), с признаком предмета по действию, выражаемым причастием (желтеющие листья — листья, которые желтеют). Термин «причастие» является калькой (буквальным переводом) с *лат.* participium.
>
> Как и прилагательные, причастия *обозначают признаки предметов*. Но, в отличие от прилагательного, выражающего *постоянный* признак (веселый человек, вкусный обед), **причастие обозначает *временный* признак** предмета: смеющийся **(сейчас)** человек, смеявшийся **(вчера)** человек; **(уже)** приготовленный обед. Временный признак может в некоторых случаях становиться постоянным. В тех случаях, когда причастие представляет действие как признак в отвлечении от времени, как постоянное свойство, способность, оно начинает употребляться в значении прилагательного. Это происходит и с действительными (мыслящее существо, пишущая машинка, красящее вещество), и со страдательными (изменяемые слова, уважаемый коллега, изолированная комната) причастиями.
>
> У причастий, употребляющихся в значении прилагательных, могут развиваться новые лексические значения, сходные со значениями качественных прилагательных: цветущий (прекрасный) вид, гнетущее (тяжелое) впечатление, расстроенное (грустное) выражение лица, блестящий (замечательный) оратор и т. п.

Это цитаты статьи Ю. В. Меньшиковой и И. Н. Смирнова.

Answer (score 1):

Переход причастий в прилагательные называется **адъективацией**, которая может быть временной или постоянной. Большая часть причастий подвергается **временной адъективации**, то есть в одних условиях выступает в качестве причастий, в других - в качестве прилагательных.

**"Асфальтированный"** при отсутствии зависимых слов - это **прилагательное**, обозначающее качественный (а не процессуальный) признак.

**Признаком адъективации**  является наличие синонимов среди прилагательных: **асфальтный, асфальтовый**, а также образование семантических рядов  с прилагательными в словосочетаниях: дороги бывают **асфальтированные, бетонные, грунтовые, гравийные, щебеночные.**

Но: **заново асфальтированный, асфальтированный в прошлом году** - это причастия при наличии зависимых слов, которые обозначают признак действия, законченного к текущему моменту, то есть процессуальный признак (эти же зависимые слов входят в глагольные словосочетания).

Кстати, асфальтировать - **двувидовой глагол**: АСФАЛЬТИРОВАТЬ, св. и нсв. (св. также заасфальтировать).

Итак, ответ на вопрос: **в русском языке  границу между причастием и прилагательным  можно обозначить появлением у причастия морфологических признаков прилагательного** (в учебниках приводится возможный ряд таких признаков), и эти признаки в каждом случае **надо найти и обозначить** .

К примеру, существуют **пары:** рассеянная туча - рассеянный человек, взволнованные люди - взволнованные лица, образованные люди - образованное вещество и т.д., здесь признаком прилагательного является появление  **условного (не прямого) значения** у исходного причастия.